# Invalid operand for inline asm constraint 'i' when writing inline x86_64 assembly

Tags: rust, inline-assembly

The code below used to build just fine back in April (Rust version ~1.6), but it doesn't anymore.

```
#![feature(asm)]

enum MyEnum { One = 1 }

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        asm!("nop" : : "i" (MyEnum::One as isize) : : ); // broken
    }
}
```

The error message does not point to any obvious changes that might be causing this.

Comment: Associated reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/5jm4ww/translating_inline_assembler_expression_from_gcc/

Comment: You are likely going to need to work to provide a [MCVE]. While I don't have Xen, [I can compile x86 assembly that is close to yours](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=35a5ab7e6dc00be69301632b88ef8851&version=nightly) just fine.

Comment: I did as you said, and it made the issue obvious. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value for the `"i"` constraint must be a compile-time constant and you are supplying it something that isn't. If you move the addition into Rust, you could use a register as well as a constant using the constraints `"ri"`.

Whether something is a constant for the purpose of inline assembler can be affected by optimization options.

Comment: This is it. Turns out that `MyEnum::MyEnumCase as isize` was once considered a compile-time constant, but isn't anymore. Minimal repro: https://gist.github.com/lilred/3868c48004ce344d87002f540d5b21f3

Comment: I've edited my question to better reflect the actual issue.